# Perl expect code is not working for setting up password

Tags: linux, perl, expect.pm

I am using perl expect to enter password in an interactive program. Perl is outputting correct password but setting it something else.

```
#!/bin/perl

use Expect;

my $hostname = qx! /usr/bin/hostname !;
my $Passwd = `./ensite_passwd solidcore $hostname`;

my $sadminPasswd = quotemeta $Passwd;
chomp $sadminPasswd;
chop $sadminPasswd;

print "password is $sadminPasswd \n\n";

my $sadminPasswd = Expect->spawn("/sbin/sadmin", "passwd")
        or die "Cannot spawn /sbin/sadmin $!\n";

 $sadminPasswd->expect(300,
              [qr/New Password:/ => sub {
                 my $fh = shift;
                 $fh->send("${sadminPasswd}\n");
                 print "sent '${sadminPasswd}'\n";
                 exp_continue;
               }
              ],
              [qr/Retype Password:/ => sub {
                 my $fh = shift;
                 $fh->send("p2c4f8j5\n");
                 #$fh->send("${sadminPasswd}\n");
                 #print "sent '${sadminPasswd}'\n";
                 print "sent 'p2c4f8j5'\n";
               }
              ]);


   $sadminPasswd->soft_close();
```

I am getting below output:

```
swdvssd0046$ sudo perl test.pl
password is p2c4f8j5 

New Password:sent 'Expect=GLOB(0x23ae188)'

Retype Password:sent 'p2c4f8j5'

Passwords do not match.
swdvssd0046$
```

I don't understand 'Expect=GLOB(0x23ae188)' at all.
I know password for this host would be "p2c4f8j5" that's why I have manually entered it in confirm password expect code.
Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

use warnings; ... "my" variable $sadminPasswd masks earlier declaration in same scope

Thanks toolic for answer!